# Why Phase1 GSM is mentioned to be a 3GPP release?

Tags: gsm, telecommunications

In some references such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GPP#Standards) (although wiki is not a reliable reference), GSM phase 1 is mentioned one of 3GPP releases while 3GPP itself is founded in 1998/1999 while GSM Phase 1 is standardized in 1992.

How that is possible. Is it a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice at the top of the Wikipedia reference that is says 3GPP are responsible for the "development and maintenance" of various standards including GSM.

Whilst GSM was developed before 3GPP was formed, I believe that given the need for interworking (including some extensions to GSM), and the fact that many of the same companies were involved in both protocol suites, the maintenance of the GSM standard was transferred to 3GPP.